# Command in sage worksheet (in sage math cloud) to get anything in sage?

Tags: python, math, compilation, sage

I'm trying to use Sageworksheet (as in Sage math cloud) for programming in Sage. If I need immediate help on something; for example, how to find the determinant of a matrix, and I want to get a command for that in sage, how should I find it? And, where should I type the command?

Also, in Sage worksheet, I observed that, after erasing an incorrect code (using the backspace button), the error notice (in red color) that comes with the compilation still remains, I cannot erase that, and even after refreshing the page, and running the empty code, the error code remains. How should I let it go when I don't need it.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using a search engine, use sagemath as a prefix or suffix to enhance results. There are many other good resources here: http://sagemath.org/doc/. If you want to get rid of error messages you can just execute the cell one more time after correcting your code.

Answer (score 5):

I would assume that

```
command?
```

still gives the documentation, and

```
command??
```

gives the source code.

Also, I would imagine that tab-completion, like

```
de[tab]
```

should give commands like `det` or something.  Ipython is still what is used there for such magic, I believe.

Or, if you have defined a matrix `M`, then

```
M.[tab]
```

would give you all available methods on that matrix, including the determinant.

Comment: No assumptions are needed for this answer, I can tell you that the above is correct.

Comment: You also might find the command search_doc("determinant") useful.

Comment: @koffie - I haven't used SMC yet so you never know how William might have slightly changed things :-) but yes, I would have been VERY surprised if this wouldn't work.

Comment: @kcrisman -- I didn't mess everything up!  I mainly "change" SMC by adding new things.  I try hard to make sure everything still works, and care a huge amount about backwards compatibility.  Also, the "way things work" in Sage traditionally is already what I think is right, so I tend to stay with it.

Answer (score -1):

Numpy has a member function that computes determinants

```
***define your matrix at Mat****
import numpy as np

determinant=np.det(Mat)
determinant
```